# File Validation before loading into Hadoop MR

Tags: validation, hadoop, mapreduce, bzip2

I have a folder of input bz2 files, and some of them might be corrupted, I want to remove all the corrupted/invalid bz2 files before running my MR job. What's a good way of doing it?

Comment: Define, "corrupted."  Do you mean that the bz2 files are malformed (unzippable), or that there is something wrong with the contents?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use bzip2 -t to test if bzip file is corrupted or not. If it's corrupted, i think you can see something like this.

```
bzip2: test1.txt: bad magic number (file not created by bzip2)
bzip2: 2: bad magic number (file not created by bzip2)

You can use the `bzip2recover' program to attempt to recover
data from undamaged sections of corrupted files.
```

So if your files are in your local file system, using some shell script based on the point mentioned above should work. If you files are already on HDFS, then use [Hadoop streaming](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r0.18.1/streaming.html) with mapper as a script to output corrupted files and no reducer, or reducer to delete or post process those files.